# Validation query formulation, SMT solver, Z3, STP

Tags: z3, smt

I have a boolean formula *`f(a, b, x, y)`*. Where *a* and *b* are boolean expressions and *x* and *y* are bit vector expressions. *a* and *b* are boolean expressions possibly using expressions *a, b, x* and *y*.

I want to define the following query for validity:

```
f(a, b, x, y)* such that *a = false && b = false 

f(a, b, x, y)* such that *a = true && b = false
```

In a way, I need to substitute the values of ***a*** and ***b*** in the formula on both the sides of implication.

Please advise how to create such a query.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a fresh variable for a?
you can then assert the following:
(assert (not a))
(assert (not b))
(assert (f a b x y))
(assert a2)
(assert (not (f a2 b x y)))
(check-sat)

your query is valid if and only if the query above is unsatisfiable because the bindings are represented as assertions and the implication was negated ( and flattened into two assertions)

Comment: Creating fresh variable for a is not possible. As a is a boolean expression possibly using expr b, x and y. Can we think of something else?